# Proper Mapping in Code First (Do I smell a many to many?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Here is the abstract concept of my model:

```
public class Apple
{    
    public int AppleID {get;set;} 
    public virtual IEnumerable<Banana> Bananas {get;set;}   
}

public class Banana 
{    
    public int BananaID {get;set;}
    public int AppleID {get;set;}
    public virtual Apple Apple {get;set;}    
}
```

Now let's say that even though that one Apple has many Bananas.

What if a Banana would have a second ***Different*** Apple of its own?

Am I missing something.  (Less than 4hours of sleep last night)

I can't add modify Banana to look like this:

```
public class Banana 
{    
    public int BananaID {get;set;}
    public int AppleID {get;set;}
    public virtual Apple Apple {get;set;}    
    public int AnotherAppleID {get;set;}
    public virtual Apple AnotherApple {get;set;}  
}
```

For clarification
"this is kinda looks like a parent / child relationship where each child has exactly one mother and one father, but parents may have many children " - P.S.W.G

Comment: Do you want a many-to-many relationship? `public virtual List<Apple> Apples {get;set;}` Or do you just want two different one-to-many relationships? `public virtual Apple OtherApple {get;set;}`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry about the typo

Comment: @p.s.w.g updated, i hope this gives more clarity

Comment: Okay one final question. Is this like a two-to-many relationship? I.e. Each `Bananas` has exactly two `Apple` objects, and of all the `Banana` objects an `Apple` has are in the same `Bananas` collection? In other words, this is kinda looks like a parent / child relationship where each child has exactly one mother and one father, but parents may have many children.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Took the fruit right out of my mouth!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are only two solutions I can think of at the moment. The first would require two different relationships. I'm going to rename your classes so it comes out a bit more clearly:

```
public class Parent
{    
    [Key]
    public int ParentID {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Father")]
    public virtual ICollection<Child> FatherOf {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Mother")]
    public virtual ICollection<Child> MotherOf {get;set;}
}

public class Child 
{    
    [Key]
    public int ChildID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Father")]
    public int FatherID {get;set;}
    public virtual Parent Father {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Mother")]
    public int MotherID {get;set;}
    public virtual Parent Mother {get;set;}
}
```

Unfortunately, this means you'll have to make to two different checks every time you want to see if a parent has a particular child. Also, you'd have to write a custom [entity validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) routine if you want to ensure that a `child.Mother != child.Father`. Of course, you could make a property that represents both sets, like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Child> Children 
{
    get { return this.FatherOf.Concat(this.MotherOf); } 
}
```

But you won't be able to use this in Linq-to-Entities queries.

The alternative, which may be simpler in the long run is to have a conventional many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Parent
{    
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child 
{    
    public int ChildID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents {get;set;}
}
```

And now write a custom entity validation routine to ensure that `Parents.Count() == 2`. The only problem here is that you won't be able to refer to the parents individually within Linq-to-Entities (at least not easily). But, as above, you make your unmapped properties to provide more convenient access to each parent individually once it's loaded into memory.

<sup>**Caveat lector:** I have not tested the above code, and it's entirely possible I'm missing a necessary attribute here or there.</sup>